# Reading SQL queries from .txt file for C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ado.net

Before, I ask my question, I want you to know that I'm quite new to winforms in C#. :) So, I'm trying to create a winform using C# and in order to get the data from the back end, I'm storing all the SQL queries in a .txt file. The format in which my SQL queries are entered in the .txt file is as follow:

```
// Caption

Query

end
```

So, in my code, I start reading the file in a loop and read until I get my required caption. Once, I get my caption, I start reading the query line by line until I reach "end". After I get my query, I EXPLICITILY replace the variables in the queries(because I know whether a query has a variable or not). For example,

```
// Caption 1

Select * from table_1 where col1 = var1;

end
```

In this case, I read the query and use string.Replace() to replace "var1" with var1.ToString(). Then, execute the query.

My question is, is there a better way to do this?Like, is there a better format to store the queries in the .txt file? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `is there a better format to store the queries in the text file?` xml? json? ......

Comment: I'm a huge proponenet of `JSON` and `JSON.NET`

Comment: your inline sql could be `var sqlQuery = getQueryFromJson("Caption 1");` and then you write a method called `public string getQueryFromJson(string caption)
{
    return result;
}`

Comment: This sounds like a very painful way to do things.  I hope you're aware of [SQL Injection errors](http://bobby-tables.com/).  `String.Replace()` is not your friend here.  Why not just have a dedicated class "mySqlStrings"?

Comment: and yes, I agree with @DanPichelman that this is painful and injection prone. I would decouple the programming and include the queries in a [Repository Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx). I would also "personally" use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET)... but hey, that's just me.

Comment: Okay, I agree that xml is text ;) and thank you for letting me know that `String.Replace()` ... is painful. I'll keep that in mind. But, I am more interested in knowing any other way to format the ".txt" file efficiently.

Comment: try using [toml](https://github.com/mojombo/toml) to format the `.txt`.  See my answer for further details

Comment: At least I would replace the "var1" with @var1 and then pass the variables as SqlParameter's for the queries. That would help you get rid of the string.Replace() and most sql-injection risks

Comment: your current "format" is not a known markup language. To make your life much easier, you should structure your text into a known one (json, xml, toml, yaml, etc)

Comment: Going through a book of development best practices may help here. You don't start building high-rise apartments without full understanding of related physics, chemistry, construction, people management etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I really appreciate it. Anyways, I just started coding. So, I have a long way to go. I'll make sure I go through some of the best practices for coding. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Warning**: I would not actually do this, but here is an attempt to answer the question. My official stance is at the bottom.

If I'm reading your question properly, your struggle is actually "parsing" the text file to get the required query. If this is the case, I would *highly* recommend not using straight `text` to accomplish this task. **You need some sort of structure so that the program knows "how" to acquire the appropriate information.** [Markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) are basically structured text that allows a program to navigate the document.

There are many markups that will work, here are a few that could fit your needs.

1. If you're trying to keep it in a `.txt` file, and keep it really simple, you could try using something like [toml](https://github.com/mojombo/toml), and parse it with [toml.net](https://github.com/rossipedia/toml-net) *or something similar*
2. A more preferred method would be to use [JSON](http://www.json.org/)(which is also text), and then use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to parse the data.
3. Lastly you could use [XML](http://www.w3.org/XML/) and parse it with the [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx)

Now, because you need to parse the data, you should create a model that stores this information.

```
// note this is a JSON example, but you can replace it with whatever Markup parser you like.
public class SqlQueriesFromJsonModel {
    public class Query{
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }

    public List<Query> Queries{ get; set; }
}
```

From here, you want to read your data from the file, and parse it into your model object.

```
SqlQueriesFromJsonModel getSqlQueries(){
    //  grab the file and parse it using json.net
    return queriesFromJson;
}
```

Call the method, and use the needed Query

```
// using System.Linq;
var queries = getSqlQueries();
var neededSqlQuery = queries.Where(Query => Query.Caption == "Caption 1");
```

*note: have wrote this in the text editor, so it might not be exact. I'm open to edits if I got something wrong.*

Now for the actual document format, here's a few options (you don't actually have to use any of these... this is just to get the creative juices flowing).

### These are all "text" formats.

**json**

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "caption": "Caption 1",
            "query": "select * from someTable"
        },
        {
            "caption": "Caption 2",
            "query": "select * from someOtherTable"
        }
    ]
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<queries>
    <query caption="Caption 1">select * from someTable</query>
    <query caption="Caption 2">select * from someOtherTable</query>
</queries>
```

**toml**

```
title = "SQL Queries"

[Caption 1]
query = "select * from someTable"

[Caption 2]
query = "select * from someOtherTable"
```

---

Now that that's out of the way, I'd like to write a disclaimer that reading your queries from a file is not a wise plan. Instead, write a [Repository Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) that handles all of your needed queries, and consider using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#.NET) to make wiring it up easier and more secure.

If you're not interested in Repositories and ORM's, at LEAST write [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) inside [Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx) within your database.

Either way, you *should* leave the text files out of it completely.. imo

Comment: Dictionary would likely be a better choice than List if you're going to store in memory. I also disagree with using a markup language to store strings only - not much benefit, and with the added PITA of escaping special characters (eg., I don't think you can even put line breaks in a toML string....a serious PITA for a SQL query).

Comment: Yeah, line breaks are a PITA in toml `bio = "GitHub Cofounder & CEO\nLikes tater tots and beer."`

Comment: I store actual data in a large .sql file - for testing purposes - that allows me to delete everything then re-add it. I presume you wouldn't say this is bad?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually against this pattern - though it is unusual, it does have some benefits (and I've done similar myself on occasion - not that that should sway your opinion). To be fair - just about everyone else here on SO (and others) will advise you to use stored procs and/or an ORM. That's certainly the mainstream and no-surprise approach, and you should strongly consider it before forging your own path.

Either way. you should definitely take heed of the advice to use parameters rather than string.Replace though. SQL Injection is a *huge* vulnerability that's ridiculously easy to prevent - there's really no excuse for it anymore.

If you continue to store your queries in files, you also may want to watch out for performance and consider caching the queries instead of hitting disk each time. Depending on your use case, you may need to deal with invalidating the cache if the file changes - something a stored proc will handle for you.

I also disagree with the comments of using a markup language for this. If you're going to store them in text files, I'd suggest a single query per file. It versions much better, is much clearer, and should offer better performance in most cases as well.

If you don't care about runtime edits or production debugging of queries, you could also compile them down to a resource file (which is normally used for things like localization). That plays well with Visual Studio, is relatively easy to implement and is a somewhat common approach.

Comment: +1 These are great thoughts, I didn't even think about versioning. Single file per query is a good approach. Resource files however, are basically another *(baked in)* markup language.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - The benefit to resource files is the VS tooling which allows you edit/view them as plain text and then only combine during compile. Personally, I wouldn't bother unless I was looking to abstract out the RDBMS differences with separate resource files (basically doing localization but for RDBMS) or wanted some (very slight) protection against production tampering.

Comment: @MarkBrackett - These are some really great inputs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that there are situnations where you do not want a stored procedure because that means one one hand there needs to be an installation before you can use the functionality and on the other you do not want another layer just to query for straight forward server or database statistics. The query is actualy is a resource and not part of the code. The only question actually is where to store it so that it would be part of the application or component. Therefore the resource file actually is not a bad idea. The only thing here to decide is whether to store it in a predefined format and use existing support code to manage it or write your own.

@Chase Florell: maybe he is writting a Repository Layer?

Comment: Another problem might be that your client need to go to the disk and fetch the query each time your executing it. Might not be a problem if it's on a central server, but if it's a real client, it might slow things down. (untested)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you cannot save the queries on the database using stored procedures?
That is usually the optimal way to store the queries as it keeps the database logic in the database.

If not, rather than using replace() you can have your varibles listed as @varname and use addwithvalue to populate the parameters with that value.

Comment: I should really consider using `AddWithValue()` instead of `String.Replace()`. Thank you for the suggestion. ;).